# Headers of a thesis: how let can I make that the "chapter" text and the number appears AFTER a \renewcommand that remove them?

Tags: header-footer, numbering, chapters, thesis, unnumbered-sections

I'm writing a PhD thesis using the "MastersDoctoralThesis" class file (version 1.6, 27/8/17 downloaded from: http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com) which is programmed to insert headers containing the number of the chapters and the "chapter" text word, and I like it. HOWEVER, my thesis should begin with an unnumbered "Introduction" chapter and then I tried to let in the headers only the text "Introduction", and I did it with the commands

```
\chapter*{Introduction}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\chaptermark{Introduction}
```

However, now the next chapters stopped showing the normal "Chapter #number#" and I don't know how to solve it. Should I put another "\renewcommand"? But with which instructions? Might it be possible to limit the field of that "\renewcommand" instruction to the sole introduction chapter?

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance ='(

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The simplest, I think, would to define two pages styles, one for the defaults headers of the template, and the other for your introduction (and other unumbered chapters, if you have any.  Then you'd have only to type `\pagestyle{…}` just before the corresponding chapters (where you need to change the page style).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've seen, you should be able to start new chapters like the introduction with the `\addchap`-command:

```latex
% \chapter*{Introduction}
% \renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
% \chaptermark{Introduction}
\addchap{Introduction}

This is my awesome introduction which is so intelligent
that it will be read by everyone everywhere.
```

This should do it:

[image: table of contents]

[image: introduction]

Comment: The class is not based on KOMA-script. It just shares a few command names. Reading the KOMA-documentation won't be helpful.

Comment: @Johannes_B, I've had another look and can't for the life of me say which template I've looked at. I could have sworn there was a `\RequirePackage{scrbook}` somewhere in there … The command still works. I'll edit the rest.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted.